# Use T4 DBContext Script to Write Display Name Attribute

Tags: entity-framework, code-generation, t4, edmx

My issue is simple: the code I'm writing is in English, but the interface is in Portuguese. Not a problem, as I can do this:

```
[Display (Name = "Símbolo")]
public string Symbol { get; set; }
```

This way, when I render my screen, it comes in Portuguese:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Symbol)
```

But...

As I am using Model First EF for my project, classes are constantly been changed by a T4 DbContext Generator. That way I can't use Display attribute, as it will be overwrited.

A solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489328/how-to-use-multiple-displayname-attribute-using-entity-framework-and-asp-net-mvc) is to extend partial classes automatically created. Kinda clumsy for me.

So my idea is to change the T4 script to get *Documentation.Summary* attribute from the EDMX model and add it as a Display Name attribute.

I found [an article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/adodotnetentityframework/thread/7f16c10a-06c5-433a-bcb5-5f214099f53c) where someone explains how to extract this data, but I'm not succeding in making it work on DbContext Generator.

Has someone ever made this? Do you guys have better ideas?

Thanks!